# Java - GXT Freeze first two columns

Tags: java, gxt

My task is to lock two first columns in my GridView with data. I looked at both topics.

[GXT 3.x : Dynamic freeze/lock columns. Autosize the grids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27376506/gxt-3-x-dynamic-freeze-lock-columns-autosize-the-grids)

[How to implement freeze column in GXT 3.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14849097/how-to-implement-freeze-column-in-gxt-3-x)

But I need sightly different thing. I want to lock two first columns like this:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/5he

**Ext** - different library from GXT(doesnt fit for me)

And what is important, Im using GridView, I **dont** want to use **TWO GRIDS**. Maybe there is possibility to freeze columns *without making two grids and putting them into verticalContainer*. I spent about 1 hour on google looking for JAVA code for that - cant find.

https://gist.github.com/branflake2267/83701cbb2699059840e1 (something like this would be best solution, but it has *two grids*)

Answer (score 0):

https://www.sencha.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-160624.html?s=022111184df68e45cc1b9de94ec9dc83

"We don't presently have plans to add this in Ext GWT 3.0.0."