# gwt grid scroll syn

Tags: java, extjs, gwt, gxt

I'm using gwt;
and I have two grids in my page. They have the same count of rows with diff contents.

I want that, when I scroll grid1,grid2 auto scroll to the same place.

Can anyone help?

I tried like this, but **this event doesn't fire**.

```
grid1.addBodyScrollHandler(new BodyScrollHandler()
    {
        @Override
        public void onBodyScroll(BodyScrollEvent event)
        {
            Info.display("test", event.getScrollTop() + "");
            //if this event fires,how to scroll grid2
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/15048539/860630, which goes into a little more depth on other parts of this general issue:

```
  grid1.addBodyScrollHandler(new BodyScrollHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onBodyScroll(BodyScrollEvent event) {
      grid2.getView().getScroller().scrollTo(ScrollDirection.TOP, event.getScrollTop());
    }
  });
  grid2.addBodyScrollHandler(new BodyScrollHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onBodyScroll(BodyScrollEvent event) {
      grid1.getView().getScroller().scrollTo(ScrollDirection.TOP, event.getScrollTop());
    }
  });
```

Comment: still no answer why event is not firing

Comment: The event "wasn't firing" since the code was listening to one grid, but not the other. The answer is to listen to both grids, and use each to scroll the other.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the approach as like this:

- Add two GridListeners to each of the GRIDS that you want on your UI
- Implement a handler for onScroll event of the first grid and add functionality to scroll the second grid

A similar implementation of the problem that you've asked has been implemented with GWT-EXT, hope that this [link](https://jaydeepm.wordpress.com/2009/08/05/gwt-ext-synchronized-scrolling-of-grids/) provides you with the basic idea though the code given there might not help you completely!